# Local site local.trekmania.com is redirecting to HTTPS. Existing solutions did not work

Tags: php, localhost, http-redirect

Suddenly my PHP site, which is developed in core PHP in localhost is trying to connect to HTTPS.

Local path: `local.trekmania.com`
`hosts` setting: `127.0.0.1 local.trekmania.com`
`apache2.conf:`

```
<Directory /var/www/wp-projects/trekmania.com>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Yesterday the site was loading fine, but today I the following error has popped up suddenly.

> This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocal.trekmania.com sent an
>   invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is happening for another site as well.

None of these sites has any `.htaccess` entry to force `HTTP` to use `HTTPS`. Both the sites are developed in core PHP. Another core PHP site, however, is loading properly. This has URL rewriting rules set in its `.htacess`.  WordPress sites are also loading OK.

Google could not help to find an answer which addresses this particular issue.

I tried the following solutions
https://galaxyinternet.us/google-chrome-redirects-localhost-to-https-fix/

And
by deleting `localhost`, `local.trekmania.com`, `127.0.0.1` under **Delete domain security policies** at `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

None of the above solutions worked even after restarting Chrome and the PC. The site is always redirecting to `HTTPS`! The same thing is happening in Firefox as well.

**OS: Ubuntu 16.04**

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you change/upgrade the browser

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry, it was a typo in the post here. I did 127.0.0.1 only.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No! I am using Chrome 81 on Linux